# How to get the position of a widget in pyqt5, while using a layout method

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

How do i get a PyQt5 widgets coordinates relative to it's parent widget? Specifically when using layout method, in my case i am using the QGridLayout layout method.

I have tried to get the widgets coordinates using the .x() and .y() methods. But both of these methods both return 0, I believe this is because i am using a layout method and that point is referring to the starting corner of the widget, which does not help in my case.

I have also tried using the mapToGlobal() and mapToParent() methods, I Do not believe I am using them correctly though,here are some examples of ways I have tried to use these two methods.

```
map_it = self.Play_label.mapFromParent(QPoint(1,1))
print ("Label coord: ", map_it)

map_it = self.Play_label.mapToParent(QPoint(1,1))
print ("Label coord: ", map_it)
```

I have also tried adding this method to the widget itself, in this case i have a class widget with the name Play_label, and i make a method in this class that prints out the mapToParent method. Below i will show an example.

```
def map_to_parent(self):
    print ("From Widget Coord: ", self.mapFromParent(QPoint(0,0)))
```

But these all return whatever i put as the QPoint, for example the first two examples will print out PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(1,1). While the last example will print out PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(). Why is this am I not using these methods correctly?

Basically what I am trying to do is use the QPropertyAnimation to change the position of the QWidget that i created, which is a QLabel that i set the Pixmap of plus various other functions. Normally you would change the geometry to change the position of a widget, but this does not work in my case of course because I am using a layout method. Here is an example of that code.

```
self.animation.setDuration(3000)
self.animation.setStartValue(QRect(0,0,200,200))
self.animation.setEndValue(QRect(width_mul, height_mul, 150, 150))
#print ("Value: ", self.animation.currentValue())
#self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.Play_label.changeImageSize)
#self.animation.setTargetObject(self.Play_label)
self.animation.start()
```

If someone could please explain to me how to get the coordinates of a widget from the parent widget when using a layout method that would be huge help, or maybe i am using the QPropertyAnimation() method wrong i am really not sure, again all i am trying to do is change the position of the widget using the QPropertyAnimation, I want it to come in from the side and move to where the widget is normally positioned, which i need the coordinates of the Widget for or some other way to move it, any advice will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advanced!

Comment: Even if you know the positions if you are using a QLayout (QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout) this will restrict the position, that is, you can not manipulate the position since that policy is handled by QLayout. Also if you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve] of your problem and currently the code that shows is not.

Comment: The widget must be outside of the layout whilst it's being moved. Once the animation is complete, the widget can then be added to the layout. There's no simple way to calculate the exact final geometry of the widget before it's been added to the layout. But then again, it's not clear why you'd need to know that anyway.